# gapi.load versus gapi.client.load

Tags: javascript, google-drive-realtime-api

In Google's JavaScript API's, what's the difference between gapi.load() and gapi.client.load()? How interchangeable are they and when should I use one versus the other? I see both are used in the Google Drive Realtime API sample code.

Answer (score 12):

As indicated by the [CORS documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors), the `gapi.load` function is used to dynamically load specific JavaScript libraries.

As documented in the description of the [`gapi.client.load`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#gapiclientloadname_version_callback) function (which is provided by the "client" JS library), `gapi.client.load` is used to build a JavaScript interface for accessing specific HTTP(S) APIs; you can also do this sort of thing yourself using API discovery (search for it to find docs) and sending API requests directly with `gapi.client.request` or CORS.

*Edit: added clarification based on [Brian Slesinsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190398/brian-slesinsky)'s follow-up comment and made minor wording changes.*

Comment: To clarify, by "API" I assume you mean HTTP(S) API's? After all any JavaScript library has an API.

Answer (score 2):

After researching this, here's my simple take:

- `gapi.load()` loads the JavaScript client library. That is to say, it's loading `gapi`. Without this `gapi` won't work.
- `gapi.client.load()` is for loading an interface for one of the many Google APIs. The loaded API interface will then be in the form `gapi.client.api.collection.method`. For example, the Moderator API would create methods like `gapi.client.moderator.series.list`.

You most likley need both.